# ReactJS - switching tabs causes unwanted scroll to top right before tab change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari, react-router-v4

I'm building a webpage with a fixed header at the very top. Currently I can navigate to two pages: **Home** and **About**.

Simple drawing of the webpage:
[image]

Both pages can get pretty tall thus I'm trying to store the scroll position for them so that when the user switches from one to the other he gets right where he was the last time. The problem is that when I switch from About to Home (or the other way arround) the current page, moments before the switch, scrolls to top and only then the new page shows up. The scroll is very fast and in result is causing a weird flicker effect (but it seems that it does not scroll the page completely to the top)

The problem occurs in **Safari** (I don't see it happening in Chrome and I haven't tested it in Opera or IE/Firefox).

The way I do it:

In the `NavigationList` (which is the fixed header) I store the scroll position of the current page right before switching to the new page. So when I click **Home** or **About** this code gets called:

```
history.push(clickedItem.pushDirectory);
localStorage.setItem(item.title, window.scrollY);
```

and then in the **Home** and **About** components I restore the scroll position this way:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const scrollPosition = localStorage.getItem("ABOUT") || 0; //or "HOME" depending on the component
    window.scrollTo(0, scrollPosition);
  }
```

And this is my code for handling the route switch. I have currently added a fade animation but even without this animation the bug occurs.

```
  <Route
    render={({ location }) => (
      <div className="contentContainer">
        <TransitionGroup>
          <CSSTransition
            key={location.key}
            classNames="fadeAnimation"
            timeout={{ enter: 300, exit: 300 }}
          >
            <Switch location={location}>
              <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
              <Route exact path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
            </Switch>
          </CSSTransition>
        </TransitionGroup>
      </div>
    )}
  />
```

Can someone tell me how to disable this scroll right before the page change or tell me a better way to preserve the scroll position of a component.